# Require dropdown selection with database populated items

Tags: php, sql-server, drop-down-menu

```
<select name="Process" id="Process">
            <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName"><?=$row["pName"]?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?></select>
```

I'm using this code to populate a dropdown from a MSSQL server database. It populates just fine. The problem I am having is by using the first "option" to show Select Process, it returns:

```
<option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">Conveyor</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">3000 Ton</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">1200 Ton</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">Cranes</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">800 Ton</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">Upender/Inverter</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">300 Ton</option>
                                <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
                <option value="pName">TPM</option>
```

I only want the "Select Process" to show up once...

Comment: You might want to google and learn about what a foreach loop does.

Comment: I know what it does. I just missed the fact that I put that inside it. But thank you for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should write `<option value="">--Select Process--</option>` outside the `foreach` loop. So This might help you.

```
<select name="Process" id="Process">
    <option value="">--Select Process--</option>
    <?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
        <option value="pName"><?= $row["pName"] ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes I did. I'm not sure how to mark these things answered yet!

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green